# Is there any way to provide different video qualities in my web application without converting each video to each format?

Tags: php, laravel, video, ffmpeg, streaming

i am building a web application which will handle thousand of videos. Currently, I am using ffmpeg to convert each video to 4 formats(1080,720,480,340px). It consumes lot of memory and time to upload for each video. Is there any best way that allows user to stream my videos in different video quality without converting each video?

Comment: You might want to look into HLS or DASH. But, no, you do have to convert each video into multiple formats. As far as memory and time, that's why queue jobs and workers exist. None of this should happen while the user is waiting in the interface. Also, there are already services that do conversion for you, like [aws transcoder](https://aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the formula to calculate video file size without compression:

width x height x bits per pixel x fps x time in seconds

This, however, isn't super helpful without knowing what kind of compression you are using. For example, a single one hour video at 720p resolution with 30fps would require 278GB without any compression.

It can be many orders of magnitude less depending on how you encode it (3% of 278GB is well within reach).

Have you seen this course: http://slhck.info/ffmpeg-encoding-course/#/